# Do not run my application after seup on Windows Vista when UAC is active

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, vista-security

I have an application and for deploying it I made setup for it by Install shield, Now after setup on windows Vista when UAC is on, my application don't run without showing every message or dialog box. Whenever when I run as administrator it run correctly.

Anyway can I setup my application as administrator? and why my application on windows 7 don't have any problems with UAC (Windows 7 only showed UAC dialog for confirmation and after confirm it work correctly) but in windows vista we don't have any message and my application don't run?

Thanks for anything.

Comment: Best practice is to remove any admin requirements or move them to in process elevation.
How are you requesting elevation and what is your code doing that needs admin access?

Comment: Thanks for reply.
but it is not possible at the moment. Now I want a solution for run it on vista like Windows 7 and if UAC confirmation showed to user my problem will be solved.

Comment: You'll need to expand your question to give more details on what you're doing, (maybe answering my question) and how it's not working.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege for the basic prinicples.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because 7 has a better UAC and Vista's UAC doesn't do the same controls that 7 do. I don't know tach specs for UAC but that's can be the answare

Comment: Yes, I know. But I want a solution for this problem because my team and I spend time more than one year for this application and if it doesn't work correctly we will lose a lot of.

Comment: So, one year ago, was only 15 years after Microsoft set the rules for limited user access...